# How to redirect user if admin pushed on submit button from another page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

At first sorry for my English.

I have made an Admin panel on the page admin.php where I have a form like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The submit is sending a TRUE to the database and stores it there.
Here comes the part where I'm stuck.

On another page user.php there is an user form like this:

```
<form action="loading.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email">
<button type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

After the user fills in the form his data also gets send to the database.
After that he gets redirected to the loading.php where he is waiting on a loading screen.

The user know must wait till the admin posts TRUE to the database. This part needs to be live, so the user is waiting on the loading screen and when the admin submits his form to the database the user gets redirected live so he don't need to refresh the page. What is the best method to perform this kind of action? Can I set a timer with an interval in AJAX to check for it? And so how do I perform this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You answered yourself. Request server every second or something and check if the admin has posted true to the database.

Comment: Yes but how to best perform this do you have like a simple script to check for it? Thanks for the help

Comment: Which side? If you have a problem with the javascript side. just put the ajax request in an interval.

Comment: Thats exactly the problem I don't know how to make the AJAX call to the database to check it with an interval. Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Side:

```
<?php // checkstatus.php
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
assert(is_numeric($user_id));

// Whatever query engine you use.
$query = 'select redirect where user_id = %user_id';
$results = runQuery($query, array('%user_id' => $user_id);
$redirect = $results->getvalue('redirect');

$response = array(
  'redirect' => $redirect,
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR);
die();
```

Javascript side (I've only done this with jquery so check this for vanilla https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-vanilla-ajax-without-jquery/):

```
function checkRedirect()
{
  $.Get('/checkstatus.php', {user_id: 10}, function(response)
  {
    if (response['redirect'])
    {
      window.location.href = '/newpage.php';
    }
  }, 'json').error(function()
  {
    // Something broke notify the user somehow. Please don't use alert.
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
}

// Must set this in global scope or interval will not be accessible inside error.add
interval = setInterval(checkredirect, 5000);
```

Comment: I'm busy with procedural PHP so I don't get all of it can you help me out with procedural PHP? Thanks and why the user_id: 10? Where does this stand for. Thanks for the great help!

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Procedural just means you are using functions instead of classes and has no real effect on the code I wrote above which is just a rough example. The `user_id: 10` was assuming you are assigning some sort of id to each person. Instead of that you can of course just store the information in the $_SESSION variable. But you need something to determine which of your users is being granted access.